# How to calculate the direction and up vector of a camera?

Tags: python, camera, mathematics, matrix

I'm trying to implement a prototype for a custom render engine using blender as content creation tool. One remaining questions is: *How can we calculate the direction and up vector of the camera by its actual position and rotation properly?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**2.8x**

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
up = cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
cam_direction = cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
```

**2.7x**

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
up = cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
cam_direction = cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() * Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
```

[image: cam coordinates]

Comment: Nice. Thank you pink vertex! I've also added a cam_direction.normalize() and up.normalize(). Works like a charm.

Comment: Since it uses `.to_quaternion`, calling `normalize` should be unnecessary because a pure rotation preserves the length of a vector, which equals 1.0 in both of these cases.

Answer (score 6):

**Alternatively**

Can get the global directions of local axes from the columns of the matrix world's rotation matrix.

```
>>> cam = C.scene.camera
>>> cam
bpy.data.objects['Camera']

>>> right, up, back = cam.matrix_world.to_3x3().transposed()
>>> cam_direction = -back
```

Comment: Yeah, good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As of Blender 2.8x, you have to use the `@` operator to multiply matrices:

```
up = cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
cam_direction = cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
```

Release Notes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API#Matrix_Multiplication

> Matrix multiplication previously used *, scripts should now use @ for multiplication (per [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)).

Comment: Not sure if it's worth finding and answering all pre @ change answers.  Added this q / a to be a "catchall" for searching on error message. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect