# Viewport position and direction

Tags: python, 3d-view

How to get Viewport Position, Direction, UpVector?
For Perspective and Ortho views.

Here is explanation Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13738/how-to-calculate-camera-direction-and-up-vector

Comment: I don't need camera. I need 3dView. Repspective/Ortho.
But not camera object.

Comment: Can you define the view-position much more clearly, this is quite an important distinction. (The point in the center of the view you look at, the point you look from?)

Comment: The point i look from.

Answer (score 8):

You can get information about the view from [RegionView3D](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D) which can be accessed via [space_data.region_3d](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.region_3d).

There are utility functions available in the [bpy_extras.view3d_utils](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html#module-bpy_extras.view3d_utils) module.

You may get the *view direction* like this

```
r3d.view_rotation * Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
```

the *up direction* should be

```
r3d.view_rotation * Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
```

and the *view location*:

```
r3d.view_matrix.inverted().translation
```

Or another way

```
region = context.region
rv3d = context.region_data
view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, (region.width/2.0, region.height/2.0))
```

Despite its name, `RegionView3D.view_location` specifies the view target.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But Ortho view does not show position correctly. Here is my video test: http://youtu.be/Ia7wjCMafqA
This line does not work in Ortho "r3d.view_matrix.inverted().translation". 
Do you know how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: I reported the issue with OrthoView here https://developer.blender.org/T43206

Comment: I added another approach according to the issue which was discussed. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

considering the answer given by pink vertex the first part is equivalent to:

```
r3d = bpy.context.area.spaces.active.region_3d
view_matrix = r3d.view_matrix
x,y,z = view_matrix.to_3x3()
```

with

```
view_dir = -z
up = y
```