# Draw 3D with Python more in front

Tags: python, add-on

I have an addon with that I draw in 3d space (lines). The vertices are where I click with the mouse cursor.

[image]

I use the region_2d_to_location to get a point from the mouse coordinates in 3d space. But I want to draw a bit more "in front" like 2 or 3 units in direction of the view camera (hope this is understandable:-))

I guess I have to manipulate the last parameter of the `region_2d_to_location` function, but how to calculate this location dependant on the current view?

I guess I can use the

```
bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_rotation
```

and then kind of multiply a vector like (2,2,2) with it to draw in a distance to the origin. Any ideas on how to do this with this Quaterion?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22963/viewport-position-and-direction) Add `scalar * view_direction_vector`  to result of region2d to 3d location.

Comment: I can get the view_direction like this:                 dir = bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_rotation * mathutils.Vector((0,0,-1))

                vec = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (x, y), (0,0,0))
                
                vec += 2.0 * dir  // but a quaternion cant be added to a vector

Comment: Oh really? Please re-check. Both `dir` and `vec` as stated above are vectors. `r3d.view_rotation` is a quaternion. A quaternion *  vector  =>  vector. Make `dir` a unit vector `vec -= 2 * dir.normalized()`.

Comment: Here is the code:

rot = bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_rotation
    
vec = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (x, y), (0,0,0))
                
dir = rot * mathutils.Vector([0,0,-1])

error: Element-wise multiplication not supported between Quaterion and vector types

Comment: Sheet man... If you are in 2.8 use @ instead of *

Comment: @batFINGER Oh man, that's it, you saved me!

Answer (score 3):

Thx to @batFINGER, here is the code that works (@ is important for multiplying Quaternion and Vector in Blender 2.8):

```
rot = bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_rotation

# Instead of adding it to the vector that is returned by region_2d_to_location_3d
# I pass it to the method as last argument
dir = rot @ mathutils.Vector((0,0,-1))
dir = dir.normalized() * -2.0

vec = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (x, y), dir)
```