# How to get 3D points of a Mesh in world space coordinates?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, camera, coordinates, world

I have a blender file with this scene (below) seen from the camera.
Now I need to get the 3D points of the mesh (the doughnut) in world space according to the camera perspective, pragmatically. Meaning I need a python script I can run to save a text file with the list of 3D points I need. I also need to know the camera direction vector.

I'm using Blender 2.83 and I have python 3.7 installed.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13738/how-to-calculate-the-direction-and-up-vector-of-a-camera

Comment: 'In world space according to the camera perspective' is rather confusing. World space is world space, whatever the camera is looking at, maybe you want camera space, or even screen space..?

Comment: out of interest why the donut picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import json

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")

bm = bmesh.new()
# write the object name you want between quotes
ob = bpy.data.objects["obj_name"]
# if Camera has a different name in your scene change it here too
cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)

points = {}
for v in bm.verts:
    obMat = ob.matrix_world
    points["V"+str(v.index)] = list(obMat @ v.co - cam.location)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(points, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: I'm getting error: "The mesh must be in editmode" on the line ```bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)```
How do I make it in edit mode?

Comment: Another thing, which points would I get in the end by this code? All set of point of the mesh, or only those facing the camera?

Comment: the first problem can be fixed by moving to the mesh editing mode, i added it in a pythonic way to the code.

Comment: All the mesh points of the object will be added

Answer (score 0):

you would need sth like this to get the object in world coordinates

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Euler, Matrix, Vector

            object_rotation = obj.rotation_euler
            object_translation = obj.location
            H_m2w = Matrix.Translation(Vector(object_translation)) @ Euler(
                object_rotation, 'XYZ').to_matrix().to_4x4()

            cam_H_m2c = H_m2w.inverted()

            cam_R_m2c = cam_H_m2c.to_quaternion().to_matrix()
            cam_t_m2c = cam_H_m2c.to_translation()
```

Comment: How do I get the 3D points still? Which of these objects I can obtain it from?